# Why is the DateInterval not handling disjoint periods correctly?

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

Consider the following as an example:

```
TimelinePlot[<|
    "DisjointPeriod"->DateInterval@{{DateObject[{2021,8,31},"Day"],DateObject[{2021,9,20},"Day"]},{DateObject[{2021,12,14},"Day"],DateObject[{2022,9,19},"Day"]}},
    "JointPeriod"->DateInterval[{DateObject[{2022,10,20},"Day"],DateObject[{2023,5,17},"Day"]}]
|>]
```

The first `DateInterval` is supposed to be a disjoint period of time. But is plotted as a single period. How do I represent disjoint periods in WL. Is this a bug?

Comment: The documentation for `DateInterval` says it's experimental, which doesn't answer the question, but just something to keep in mind. Second, as I read the documentation it's not at all clear to me that `DateInterval` can represent disjoint intervals. You can clearly use disjoint date ranges as arguments to `DateInterval`, but it sounds to me like the resulting interval is just always equivalent to the date range between the earliest and latest dates. So, I guess you're going to have to break out your disjoint range into separate `DateInterval`s.

Comment: Having said that, `Interval` does seem able to represent disjoint regions, so...?

Comment: When you expand the the summary box for the resulting DateInterval it is clear that it does support disjoint intervals. I think that it is just not supported by TimelinePlot.

Comment: It clearly can hold disjoint date ranges as part if its data, but the semantics are not obvious to me. For example, the summary box says "Beginning:..." and "Through:...", which one could assume means "this date interval represents the date range beginning at ... and running through ...". Now, I would certainly expect that it can represent disjoint date intervals. I'm just saying that neither the documentation nor the front end representation say definitively that it does. Combine that with the fact that with it being experiemental, and I would say it's not appropriate to consider it a bug.

Comment: But I think it likely that you're correct about TimelinePlot being the culprit here. I just don't yet think that conclusion is definitive.